# Which is better Redis on Lumen or Laravel?

Tags: laravel, redis, lumen

I just learned about Redis and I want to try create a scalable Web Application, to achieve this I'm going to use Laravel as the main and Lumen as the microservice (API). So after I learned about Redis, I want to add it to my project, but I confused and tried to get a explanation from google, but no luck. I still confused after read a lot of tutorials.

My questions are:

1. Should I make it separated from the server? (because I saw it on
   Docker, redis will be on separated container)
2. Should I append it to the Laravel? (because it's the main)

Thank you

Comment: "Should I make it separated from the server?" - you can't "include" Redis in your Laravel app, if you're about that. Redis is an independent app. Separate daemon, separate port, you know.

Comment: Sorry, I think my questions aren't clear, what I mean is like this ex: 1 container for laravel, 3 container for lumen, and 1 more for redis (using lumen as well) @Tarasovych

Comment: That's all about your choice. Depends on your scale, server resources, etc.

Comment: @Tarasovych yes I aware that, I don't have any problem with the server resources, for the scale it'll be big so that's why I want to make a scalable web app. what I want to know is the best performance for my web app is only using 1 redis for `N` microservices or create `N` redis for each `N` microservices

Answer (score -1):

To connect redis to Laravel see [laravel official document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redis)

To connect lumen to redis see this links:

1. [lumen doc for cache](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache)
2. [lumen doc for queue](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues)

**You can put your redis in any server you want and connect it to laravel or lumen with (in your `.env` file)**:

```
REDIS_Host="yout server"
REDIS_port="port of your server to connect redis"
REDIS_password="password which set in redis"
```

NOte: You are not force append redis to laravel if you need it in lumen just!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but I already read about the redis from Laravel and Lumen doc (which is refers to Laravel as well). And I still confuse about it where to use it.

So do you think it's better to use a separate server? what I can think about it now is that I'll use the redis on each microservices as the main website will be calling all the microservices, do you have any other opinion? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all, Redis is an in-memory data structure that is used as a database, cache and message broker [What is Redis](https://redis.io/topics/introduction). It is similar to the database (DB) you would connect to but not something you can include in your app.

It sits somewhere, running as a daemon and you connect to it for the purposes of caching or message brokering, etc.

2. Now that you know you cannot append to it, do you want faster caching or session management? do you have the resources to support it? If yes, then you should connect to Redis.

Kindly take notice of something however, if you are going to run both Lumen and Laravel on the same system, you have to make certain changes to both environment files for the two applications.

eg. `.env` (Laravel app), you can change things like `REDIS_HOST` to `REDIS_HOST_LARAVEL` while you maintain it for `.env` (Lumen app). Another example is `DB_HOST` to something else like `MY_DB_HOST` and change them accordingly in the `config/` files.

For some reason they can behave weird running to Lumen or Laravel apps on the same server connecting to Redis for cache or session management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! what do you mean they can behave weird when connecting redis to Lumen or Laravel on the same server? May I know what kind experience did you have when you put them on the same server? is it the performance sometimes slow and sometimes fast?

Comment: Not performance wise, but behavior wise. Sometimes you get DB connectivity failure and app temporarily crashes because it is ignoring the contents of both `.env` and what is cached from `artisan config:cache` but instead defaulting to things like `Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` or sometimes one application will get access denied attempting to connect to the other App's DB